# PyQT5 Checkbox changing indicator and tick colour

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt

I am require to design a UI by using QT Designer in black colour background.
My source is written in python and using PyQT5 (execute with python3)

Now I am facing the difficulties in using QCheckbox where the box colour is follow the background colour of the QCheckbox. So I changed the box colour to white in stylesheet.
However, when the box is in white, the tick is unable to see which I believe the tick becomes white as well. I try to find is there anyway way to change the tick colour to black but unable to.

Does anyone came across this issue?
My source is as below:

```
########################
#   Import             #
########################
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from main_ui import Ui_MainWindow as QT_Main
import os
os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.ui = QT_Main()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.showMaximized()

        self.ui.checkBox.setStyleSheet("QCheckBox::indicator{color:black;background-color:white;}"
                                       "QCheckBox{color:white}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
        if app is None:
            app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        else:
            print('QApplication instance already exists: %s' % str(app))
        window = MainWindow()
        window.show()
        app.exec_()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    except Exception as e:
        expstr = str(getattr(e, 'message', str(e)))
```

PyQt5 UI File in python is as below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'main_ui.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.0
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1005, 800)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(38, 38, 38);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(89, 89, 89);")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_2)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_2)
        self.frame_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(98, 98, 98);")
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_3)
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.frame_2)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.checkBox.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.checkBox.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.checkBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 20))
        self.checkBox.setStyleSheet("")
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_2)
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 300))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tableView.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tableView.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tableView.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 500))
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableView, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1005, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
```

Comment: The "checked" symbol does not follow the QSS style colors as it's completely painted by the current style. If you want to use custom colors, you need to use a [QProxyStyle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html) or subclass QCheckBox and override its `paintEvent()`. Alternatively, use a custom image/icon as explained in [Customizing QCheckBox](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcheckbox). Btw, for future reference, try more efforts in providing a [mre]: your example doesn't need a UI or pyuic file, just create a basic widget, set a layout and add the required widget(s).

Comment: @musicamante Hi, finally able to do it. thank you very much for your guide. i loaded white rectangle image into the checkbox. 
Noted for your advice. Thanks a lot and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overcome the black background issue with QCheckbox, can simply load white image in stylesheet.

My code for my sample is as below

```
self.ui.checkBox.setStyleSheet("QCheckBox::indicator"
                                       "{"
                                       "background-image:   url(/home/pi/System/test/white.png);"
                                       "width:40px;"
                                       "height:40px;"
                                       "}")
```